# window scroll - showing div - function for many divs - pure js

Tags: javascript, foreach, scroll

I'm at the stage of learning javascript, and I have a problem.

I wrote the code, adding class to div and showing it after scrolling to a specific section. My code:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
const picture2 = document.querySelector('.box2-pic');
const section2 = document.querySelector('.box2');
const section2Top = section2.getBoundingClientRect().top;


const picture3 = document.querySelector('.box3-pic');
const section3 = document.querySelector('.box3');
const section3Top = section3.getBoundingClientRect().top;

if (window.pageYOffset >= section2Top) {
    picture2.classList.add('visible');
} 

if (window.pageYOffset >= section3Top) {
    picture3.classList.add('visible');
}
```

});

However, what if I would like to collect all such elements and add them to one function? In each section is one div and I want to add showing animation after scroll.

At the moment, each div and section is downloaded separately.
I've get all divs and sections  them by **querySelectoAll** and I do something like this:

```
const pictures = document.getElementsByClassName('.allPics'); 
const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section'); 

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sections[i].getBoundingClientRect().top) {
        pictures[i].classList.add('visible');
        }
    }})
```

however, it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Is possible to write that function in **pure javascript?** 
Could you please help me to understand how should I correct this? :)

Comment: @VíñịtVịłłă I believe it's more likely the case that the `.` is not required, as it's a query on class name, rather than a query selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem with the code you have is that `pictures[i]` may not be accessible, as `i` is an iterator over the length of the sections, rather than pictures.

In a lot of cases, a `forEach` is an easier pattern, as you don't need to worry about the state of a variable which is only being used to iterate over a collection.

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't allow a `forEach`, but you can use `querySelectorAll`, which does. I've used arrow functions, which in many ways are the same as a regular function, but with a slight space saving (the differences are important but not relevant here)

I'm not entirely sure from what you've presented whether or not the example below does *exactly* what you want, but I believe it should show an example of what is possible and how that might be achieved.

```js
const pictures = document.querySelectorAll('.allPics');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= section.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
      const sectionPictures = section.querySelectorAll('.allPics');
      sectionPictures.forEach(picture => picture.classList.add('visible'));   
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.section {
  border: solid 3px rgba(20, 20, 30, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 30vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
</div>

<div class="section">
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
</div>

<div class="section">
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
</div>

<div class="section">
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
</div>

<div class="section">
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
  <img class="allPics" src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Now this is clear for me. I wanted to use forEach but have no idea how to connect these all elements.   Thank you! :)

Comment: @Klaudia glad it worked, feel free to comment if there are any problems